# Помогите с TextView и Linkify

Tags: java, android

В `TextView` приходит текст с ссылками, хочу сделать их кликабельными.

Делаю так:

```
TextView tv_contatti2 = new TextView(this); 
tv_contatti2.setText(contatti);
Linkify.addLinks(tv_contatti2, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
tv_contatti2.setLinksClickable(true);
```

но когда нажимаю на ссылку, то вылетает ошибка:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
    at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:75)
    at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8325)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9300)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените:

```
TextView tv_contatti2 = new TextView(this);
```

на

```
TextView tv_contatti2 = new TextView(ctx);
```

Comment: У меня getApplicationContext() и стоит

Comment: @sviter-pro, Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!! А как мне эту ссылку отловить? всмысле хочу открывать ее своем WebView

Comment: @sviter-pro, Насколько я понимаю, ссылка у Вас содержится в `contatti`.

Comment: просто с ней еще и содержиться текст! все в перемешку! просто не понимаю как отделить ее от всего текста

Comment: просто если вытащить всю TextView tv_contatti2 через PUTEXTRA, то вытаскивается все с текстом

Comment: @sviter-pro, Вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23158224) описывается что-то подобное.